# Angular 2 / Ionic 2 TypeError: zxcvbn_1.default is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-testing

Testing with Jasmine and Karma, 
I am using the `zxcvbn` library to do some password strength calculations.
This fails when I try to run a spec on it, by calling the `updateScore()` function below.

```
private updateScore(): void {
    const analysis = zxcvbn(this.password)
    this.score = analysis.score;
    this.comment = analysis.feedback.warning || analysis.feedback.suggestions[0];
  }
```

In the import, I am doing `import zxcvbn from 'zxcvbn';`

This works in the app, and even when I build and emulate, but in the spec, it gives me that error:

```
FAILED TESTS:
  PasswordStrengthChecker
    ✖ should update the score when password changes
      Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.11.6)
    TypeError: zxcvbn_1.default is not a function
        at PasswordStrengthChecker.updateScore (webpack:///src/components/password-strength-checker/password-strength-checker.ts:25:28 <- src/test.ts:93920:40)
        at PasswordStrengthChecker.ngOnChanges (webpack:///src/components/password-strength-checker/password-strength-checker.ts:20:9 <- src/test.ts:93916:14)
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/components/password-strength-checker/password-strength-checker.spec.ts:27:13 <- src/test.ts:185997:18)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:232:0 <- src/test.ts:183822:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:130574:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:231:0 <- src/test.ts:183821:32)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:114:0 <- src/test.ts:183704:43)
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:102:0 <- src/test.ts:130289:34)
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem when using

`import linkifyStr from 'linkifyjs/string';`

instead of

`import * as linkifyStr from 'linkifyjs/string';`

Comment: Thanks! your answer solved my problem when I was testing angular 2 components that depends of moment-timezone. I had this error when ran ng test: moment_timezone_1.default is not a function
After change the import It works like a charm.